# Is it bad practice to save complex data objects as JSON into Room DB Android?

Tags: android, android-room

Lets say I want to save complex objects containing multiple lists of other objects as JSON into a Room table on Android. Would this be considered bad practice? Does it affect performance noticably?

Or should I instead for example split the object into different Tables and only persist the ids in the main object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real definitive answer.

- From a relational database, which SQLite is, aspect it would be considered bad practice to store JSON representations, as the complex objects are related.

  - It is also very likely that the data would not be normalised, which is considered bad practice from a database point of view.
- From a storage aspect it would be considered bad practice as you are storing more data than necessary (the separators and field/member descriptors).

  - Storing and retrieving, especially the latter, for Android can be inefficient as underlying the retrieval is a Cursor, which buffers the data into blocks that consist of complete rows of data. The fewer rows per block can result in less efficient retrieval.
- If you are expecting to extract data based upon the fields within objects then searching/comparing within embedded lists, as opposed to related tables, is fraught with complexities.
- If you simply want to manipulate the objects after they have been retrieved then it can be considered simpler to use a JSON representation, at least in the short term.

You may wish to consider the answer provided here [Android Studio Type Converters with complex objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71501695/android-studio-type-converters-with-complex-objects/71503955#71503955)